# Word for widespread problem

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with an noun that communicates a widespread problem.  Namely, the fact that 1 person has such a problem isn't a bad thing, but the fact that so many people have this problem is the issue.

I've come up with *pandemic*, but a pandemic is a huge problem that is also widespread.

What's the word for a little problem that is made big because it is widespread?

Comment: Prevalent: Widespread in a particular area or a particular time.  Insidious: Proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with very harmful effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

This problem has become *rampant.*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Pervasive** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervasive))

> spread throughout

*Pervasive* is generally used in a negative sense, but not always.

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to work with it since it's a verb, but the word [snowball](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snowball) fits the description of a small thing that rapidly increases in both size and importance.

Answer (score -1):

The problem has become *epidemic*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved if you could provide an explanation or examples of how *epidemic* would be used, including any suitable references. I encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for further guidance.

Answer (score -2):

This is a person that I would describe as one who has *issues*.